# call external javascript functions inside vue instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Below is the set of external javascript functions that I'm calling from a vue instance

```js
// debounce
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    let timeout;
    
    return function() {
        let context = this, args = arguments;
        later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
    
        let callNow = immediate && !timeout;

        clearTimeout(timeout);

        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);

        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
}
// -- end debounce

// animate css
function animateCss(element, animationName, callback) {
    const node = document.querySelector(element)
    node.classList.add('animated', animationName)
    
    function handleAnimationEnd() {
        node.classList.remove('animated', animationName)
        node.removeEventListener('animationend', handleAnimationEnd)
    
        if (typeof callback === 'function') callback()
    }
    
    node.addEventListener('animationend', handleAnimationEnd);
}
// -- end animate css
```

and my vue instance

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: '#search-tpl',
    methods: {
        onKeyDown: debounce(function(){
            animateCss('#searchboxui-wrapper', 'fadeOutDown',function(){
                document.querySelector('#searchboxui-wrapper').style.display = 'none';  
            });
        }
    }
})
```

but it always throws me `undefined`, even if I declare the [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) package or socketio package, it throws me `undefined`, any help, ideas please?

PS: I'm using Vue CLI 3

[image]

Comment: How do you import the things you wanna use in `Search.vue` ?

Comment: Are you using webpack or any other build process, or just including vue.js directly into a .html page?   (If you're using .vue files you just need to `import` whatever external libraries each component is using, so webpack knows to include them).  Can you show the code where you're currently trying to "declare the axios package"?

Comment: @DanielBeck webpack, and im on vue cli

Comment: @Archie I'm using vue CLI, so im declaring the imports from the app.vue

Comment: Ah, that's probably the problem.  You need to declare the import in the vue file where you're using the imported code, not in app.vue.

Comment: @DanielBeck just did, still gives me "undefined" error/ not defined error

Comment: @DanielBeck also jud did tried to declare it from the main.js (generated by vue cli) just to make it runs global but unfortunately still returns undefined

Comment: Does your external file `export` the functions?  @niklaz's answer below shows exactly how this should work.  If that doesn't seem to fix it, please show the import / export code in the question, it's hard to debug based on a description.

Comment: @DanielBeck did tried the answer below by "import { debounce, animateCss } from './search-util.js';
" and did insert it to the top most part of main.js (default file generated by vue cli) but unfortunately, still gives me "undefined" error

Comment: @DanielBeck did manually put all the codes from the external file (not using import) to the search.vue and seems working but a bit untidy, any ideas why its now working when using import?

Comment: @JuliverGalleto, can you place the sample of working code? My sample should be working, but not sure how you have placed it. Thanks

Comment: "any ideas why its not working when using import"  My guess is that your external file isn't using `export`.

Answer (score 2):

Create external js file, say `externals.js`, use import to import everything or  specific functions from this file and use them in your Vue code:

Content in externals.js:

```js
// debounce
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    let timeout;

    return function() {
        let context = this, args = arguments;
        later = function() {
            timeout = null;

            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        
        let callNow = immediate && !timeout;

        clearTimeout(timeout);

        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);

        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
}
// -- end debounce
        
// animate css
function animateCss(element, animationName, callback) {
    const node = document.querySelector(element)
    node.classList.add('animated', animationName)
        
    function handleAnimationEnd() {
        node.classList.remove('animated', animationName)
        node.removeEventListener('animationend', handleAnimationEnd)
        
        if (typeof callback === 'function') callback()
    }
        
    node.addEventListener('animationend', handleAnimationEnd);
}
// -- end animate css

export {debounce, animateCss}
```

Content in VueJS:

```js
import {debounce, animateCss} from '../../js/externals.js'
    
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: '#search-tpl',
    methods: {
        onKeyDown() {
            debounce(function() {
                animateCss('#searchboxui-wrapper', 'fadeOutDown', function() {
                    document.querySelector('#searchboxui-wrapper').style.display = 'none';
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @JuliverGalleto, can you update the question with corrected sample? It should be working. If it is not working, then something else is the cause of error